# How to use spark mllib in web project

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to use spark `mllib.jar` in web project. I downloaded `spark-1.1.0-bin-hadoop2.4` and unzipped. There are some jar found as follows:

> datanucleus-api-jdi-3.2.1.jar
>
> datanucleus-core-3.2.2.jar
>
> datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.1.jar
>
> spark-assembly-1.1.0-hadoop2.4.0.jar
>
> spark-examples-1.1.0-hadoop2.4.0.jar

Then I use `spark-assembly-1.1.0-hadoop2.4.0.jar` to import classification methods. It can be run successfully in java project. However when I add the jar to `SomeWebProject/web-inf/lib`, it turns out error messages:

```
validateJarFile ...\web-inf\lib\spark-assembly-1.1.0-hadoop2.4.0.jar jar not loaded. offending class:javax/servlet/servlet.class
```

I know it because my web project javax.servlet class is duplicated with spark jar. I try to delete spark's `javax.servlet`. It still not working.

Could you please tell me how to figure it out

and

Can I use other spark jar to run `mllib` in local mode. This jar is too large and it is about `132 mb` and I think some of them are useless. But I cannot find any other available jars. Is this jar the only way to import `spark-mllib.jar`?
p.s. For some reasons I can not deploy spark in my servers. So I could not use hadoop environments

Thanks very much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use maven then just add these dependencies to your pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This can be very userful